# Windows 7 Activation with Virtual Hardware

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-activation

I'm looking for a type of hypervisor that has full hardware virtualization so that a Windows 7 activation will never become invalid in the future.

I've read that some hypervisors use the host system's actual CPU hardware in the guest OS environment. However, I am thinking that this would pose a problem with a Windows 7 activation that ties itself to the system hardware.

This would be a backup system for someone who may need to access Windows files or programs in the future without having to go through the hassle of reactivating.

Can someone recommend a hypervisor that would work well with full hardware virtualization? Are there any other issues I need to consider for this type of setup?

Answer (score 1):

Doing specifically what you ask is not allowed under Windows licensing. It's not really that for example a virtual machine or hypervisor can't set a virtual serial number it's that it's not that hard for the OS to tell its in a VM and thus shouldn't use those numbers to validate anything.

You could use Windows 7 Pro or higher with Hyper-V. The guest OS of Windows 7 would also be licensed. You could also do Windows 7 Pro or Enterprise with KMS licensing then relying on a physical hardware Windows server. Windows Server Datacenter would also work.

There are other ways to do it that do not address the fact that you need external tools or need to reactivate each boot etc. For example VMWare Tools does this by just storing the keys and activating every boot.